# How to access a file using "file_put_contents" in PHP?

Tags: php

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/connectionClass.php');

class webcamClass
{
    public $imageFolder = "ABC";

    //This function will create a new name for every image captured using the current data and time.
    public function getNameWithPath()
    {
        $name = $this->imageFolder . date('D/M/Y') . ".jpg";
        return $name;
    }

    //function will get the image data and save it to the provided path with the name and save it to the database
    public function showImage()
    {
        $file = file_put_contents($this->getNameWithPath(), file_get_contents('php://input'));
        if (!$file) {
            return "ERROR: Failed to write data to " . $this->getNameWithPath() . ", \n";
        } else {
            $this->saveImageToDatabase($this->getNameWithPath()); // this line is for saving image to database
            return $this->getNameWithPath();
        }

    }

    //function for changing the image to base64
    public function changeImagetoBase64($image)
    {
        $path   = $image;
        $type   = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $data   = file_get_contents($path);
        $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
        return $base64;
    }

    public function saveImageToDatabase($imageurl)
    {
        $image = $imageurl;
        //        $image=  $this->changeImagetoBase64($image);          //if you want to go for base64 encode than enable this line
        if ($image) {
            $query  = "Insert into snapshot (Image) values('$image')";
            $result = $this->query($query);
            if ($result) {
                return "Image saved to database";
            } else {
                return "Image not saved to database";
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Not able to access a file using file_put_contents.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your file path. For example you access to `ABCSat/Jun/2017.jpg`! I think you try to access `ABC/Sat/Jun/2017.jpg`, so add `/` or `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` at the end of `$image_folder`:

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/connectionClass.php');

class webcamClass
{
    public $imageFolder = "ABC" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    //This function will create a new name for every image captured using the current data and time.

    public function createDirectories($file_name = ''){
        $directories = explode('/', $file_name);

        $dir_path = '';
        for($i = 0; $i < count($directories) - 1; $i++) {
            $dir_path .= $directories[$i] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
            if(!file_exists($dir_path)) {
                mkdir($dir_path);
            }
        }
    }

    public function getNameWithPath()
    {
        $name = $this->imageFolder . date('D/M/Y') . ".jpg";
        $this->createDirectories($name);
        return $name;
    }

    //function will get the image data and save it to the provided path with the name and save it to the database
    public function showImage()
    {
        $file = file_put_contents($this->getNameWithPath(), file_get_contents('php://input'));
        if (!$file) {
            return "ERROR: Failed to write data to " . $this->getNameWithPath() . ", \n";
        } else {
            $this->saveImageToDatabase($this->getNameWithPath()); // this line is for saving image to database
            return $this->getNameWithPath();
        }

    }

    //function for changing the image to base64
    public function changeImagetoBase64($image)
    {
        $path   = $image;
        $type   = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $data   = file_get_contents($path);
        $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
        return $base64;
    }

    public function saveImageToDatabase($imageurl)
    {
        $image = $imageurl;
        //        $image=  $this->changeImagetoBase64($image);          //if you want to go for base64 encode than enable this line
        if ($image) {
            $query  = "Insert into snapshot (Image) values('$image')";
            $result = $this->query($query);
            if ($result) {
                return "Image saved to database";
            } else {
                return "Image not saved to database";
            }
        }
    }

    public function query($query) {
        $dbObj = new dbObj();
        $conn = $dbObj->getConnstring();
        return mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    }


}
```

Comment: Warning: file_put_contents(ABC/Sat/Jun/2017.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\A\captureupload\webcamClass.php on line 15
ERROR: Failed to write data to ABC/Sat/Jun/2017.jpg. This is my error.

Comment: This error occured because directory not exist. I updated my answer and add createDirectories function, please try it. @Karthik

Comment: I have created a directory or folder but still not able to access a file or folder still getting:    Warning: file_put_contents(imageSat/Jun/2017.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\A\captureupload\webcamClass.php on line 32
ERROR: Failed to write data to imageSat/Jun/2017.jpg,

Comment: Thank you for your help sir.

Comment: `imageSat/Jun/2017.jpg` not in your question! Are you add `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` at the end of `$imageFolder`? @Karthik

Comment: You're welcome. If it worked, please accept this answer. If not, tell me. @Karthik

Comment: $result = $this->query($query);  This line is not able to executing Please help me.

Comment: `$this->query($query);` call `query` function in this class, but you don't have `query` function. @Karthik

Comment: Please add a query to the program.

Comment: I think you have a database connection in `connectionClass.php` file. Please add it to your question, because running query need database connection. @Karthik

Comment: I am not able to add code but that file contains the only database connection.

Comment: Why?! If i write my db connection, you can't use it. because most probably
 it is incompatible with your db connection. @Karthik

Comment: I updated my answer and add `query` function. @Karthik